# Перевод числа с помощью массива с побитовым умножением

Tags: c++

Есть программа, которая выводит вещественное число в представлении памяти компьютера,его характеристику, мантиссу и затем обратно переводит в вещественное число для определения погрешности в вычислениях. Как можно заменить текущий перевод вещественного числа на перевод с помощью массив с побитовым умножением на десять в двоичной системе счисления?Sos

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// печать int в двоичном виде
void PrintBinFromInt(const int number) {
    const char* num = (char*)&number;
    int len = sizeof(int) - 1;
    bool firstZeros = true;
    // печать каждого бита
    for (int j = 7; j >= 0; j--) {
        if (!firstZeros || j == 0) {
            printf("%i", (num[0] >> j) & 1);
        }
        else {
            if ((num[0] >> j) & 1 != 0) {
                printf("%i", (num[0] >> j) & 1);
                firstZeros = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
void PrintFloat(float number) {
    // преобразование int в массив char
    const char* num = (char*)&number;
    // расчет длины
    int len = sizeof(float) - 1;
    char* b = new char[len * 8];
    int bcount = 0;
    // для каждого байта
    for (int i = len; i >= 0; i--) {
        // каждый из 8 битов помещаем в массив
        for (int j = 7; j >= 0; j--) {
            b[bcount] = (num[i] >> j) & 1;
            bcount++;
        }
    }
    unsigned long long sign,      // знак
        mantissa,   // мантисса
        har;        // характеристика
    // преобразование числа в массив целых неотрицательных чисел
    unsigned int* ptr = (unsigned int*)&number;
    // знак: 0 - плюс, 1 - минус
    sign = *ptr >> 31;
    // поиск характеристики
    har = *ptr << 1;    //  устранение бита, который отвечает за знак
    har >>= 1;
    har >>= 23;
    // поиск мантиссы
    mantissa = *ptr << 9;
    mantissa >>= 9;
    mantissa = mantissa | 040000000;
    // поиск порядка
    unsigned long long por = har - 127;
    // вывод
    printf("V pamyati:\t\t\t");
    for (int i = 0; i < bcount; i++) {
        printf("%i", b[i]);

        if (i == 0 || i == 8) printf("|");
    }
    printf("\n\nHarakteristika:\t\t");
    // характеристика - с 1 по 9 бит
    for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
        printf("%i", b[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\nPoryadok:\t\t%d", por);
    // мантисса - с 9 по 32 бит
    printf("\n\nMantissa:\t\t");
    for (int i = 9; i < bcount; i++) {
        printf("%i", b[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\nVeshestvennoye chislo:\t\t\t");
    // поиск целой части
    unsigned long long a = 23 - por;
    unsigned long long  cel = mantissa >> a;
    // поиск дробной части
    unsigned long long  k = mantissa << (41 + por);
    k >>= (41 + por);
    // выводим "-", если знак отрицательный
    if (sign == 1) printf("-");
    //  целая часть
    printf("%d,", cel);
    // чтобы позже написать и в двоичном кода, скопируем
    unsigned long long  kBin = k;
    // умножаем на 10, чтобы перевести дробную часть в десятичный вид
    while (k != 0) {
        k *= 10;
        unsigned long long a = k;
        a >>= (23 - por);
        printf("%d", a);
        k <<= (41 + por);
        k >>= (41 + por);
    }
    printf("\n\nDvoichniy vid:\t");
    // выводим "-", если знак отрицательный
    if (sign == 1) printf("-");
    // целая часть в бинарном виде
    PrintBinFromInt(cel);
    printf(",");
    // умножаем на 2, чтобы получить двоичный вид
    while (kBin != 0) {
        kBin *= 2;
        unsigned long long a = kBin;
        a >>= (23 - por);
        printf("%d", a);
        kBin <<= (41 + por);
        kBin >>= (41 + por);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    float f;
    printf("Vvedite veshestvennoye chislo: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &f);
    PrintFloat(f);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В битах не может существовать погрешности вычисления. Погрешность может получиться при работе с дробными числами, при работе с целыми числами - нету погрешности. Что за *побитовое умножение на 10* не понятно.

Comment: Вот и я не особо могу понять, но преподаватель требует чтобы перевод был через него

Comment: Уточните у преподавателя, он имеет в виду преобразование числа с плавающей точкой по сути из строкового представления десятичными цифрами опять во внутренний формат?

Comment: На данный момент такой возможности нет, но если бы это было так, как вы сказали, как бы это примерно выглядело?

Comment: Что-нибудь в духе [__floatscan](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/internal/floatscan.c) (вызывается из `fscanf()` при чтении числа с плавающей точкой)  (только от вас хотят еще и умножение на 10 промоделировать)